# Haskell Equivalent of Json or Edn

Tags: haskell, clojure

In Javascript, if I want to store a configuration, I use Json. In Clojure, I use EDN, what is recommended in Haskell? Yaml?

Comment: You can use JSON, Haskell is quite good at JSON as it turns out.  The `aeson` library is popular for this.  There's also a plethora of other libraries out on hackage for configuration purposes.  Use whatever you want.  YAML can be parsed easily, INI would be almost trivial, make your own format for all I care.  Haskell has libraries that make it really easy to write parsers, so you can use whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is: all of the above! Haskell has libraries for [JSON](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson), [EDN](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedn), [YAML](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml), [CSV](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava), and many more. I believe all of these libraries have support for generic programming, which means they can automatically derive a schema for you.

An example using JSON, would be:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Aeson

data Foo = Foo { fooA :: Int, fooB :: Char, fooC :: String }
  deriving (Generic)

instance ToJSON Foo
instance FromJSON Foo
```

Now you can use `encode` or `decode` on you `Foo`s without any more work.

A simpler, but less recommend, option would be to use `Read` and `Show`:

```
data Foo = ... as before
  deriving (Read, Show)
```

This would allow you to do `show (Foo ...)` and `let foo = read someString`.

Comment: Depending on the application, it may be useful to consider something like the `persistent` package.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `instance FromJSON Foo`?  I think you accidentally a `Foo` there.

Comment: @bheklilr I did indeed accidentally a `Foo`. Thanks!